# Postgres port conflict with -k

Tags: postgresql

I'm running `postgres` with `-k /tmp/tmp-postgres/`, but I'm getting a port conflict vs my main postgres.

I am running another postgres listening on that port, but I was under the impression that running with a socket directory set would make it use a unix socket instead of tcp, and that it wouldn't need a tcp port. What am I doing wrong?

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -F -k /tmp/tmp-postgres/ -D /tmp/tmp-postgres/
LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

The context here is setting up a temporary postgres for integration testing; I'm open to other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the database in another directory and start it on another port and try to connect on that port.

Comment: The directory is actually from `mktemp`, it's not conflicting. I did change the port number and now it's working

Comment: @Daenyth if it was helpfull, you may accept and upvote the answer.